# Problems while invoking swi-prolog from PHP

Tags: php, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to execute a swi-prolog file from PHP, but when i try to run this code, nothing is executed. This my code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Calling SWI-Prolog from PHP (short)</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body>
<H1>Calling SWI-Prolog from PHP (short)</H1>

<? 
  $cmd = "nice -n15 /C:/Program Files/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe -f test.pl -g test,halt";
?>

<P>
<PRE>
<? 
  system( $cmd );
  echo "\n";

  $output = exec( $cmd );
  echo $output;
  echo "\n";

  exec( $cmd, $output );
  print_r( $output );
  echo "\n";

  $output = shell_exec( $cmd );
  echo $output;
  echo "\n";
?> 
</PRE>
</P>

</body>
</HTML>
```

When I run the php file from my server, it only shows the string `Calling SWI-Prolog from PHP (short)`.

Answer (score 0):

Activate error reporting and you probably will see some info showing what went wrong.

Add this at the beginning of the file:

```
<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", "1");
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

When done debugging you should remove the lines. You should never print error output in a productive environment.